# Sticky table header when scrolled in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, sticky

I am trying to create a table header which gets fixed at a certain. Here is a sample I have worked on(this is what i really need in AngularJS) http://plnkr.co/edit/cxZzrMeiYyaoQQOotX3H?p=preview  but it doesn't work in a real application, I am not sure what am I missing on. It would be great to get some suggestions and maybe sample of code .

```
vm.testScroll = function() {
    console.log("insideTestScroll---");
    var window_top = $($window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        console.log(window_top + " " + div_top);
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        console.log(window_top + " " + div_top);
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
    console.log("after removeClass!");
};

console.log("entering testScroll function call-");
$window.onscroll = vm.testScroll();
console.log("running windowScroll");
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want to replace the sticky header with the next header and make that sticky if you're at that scroll position?

Comment: @AWolf , " i want the same behaviour  that is happening in the plnkr i provided ",the issue is, it is not working in the real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the process is always to use directive when manupulating the html DOM,now the new issue is i am trying to implement this on a table header and the table header shrinks to the header data width,"what a DRAG!!!!!",here is the sample code
//Table HeaderLocking-------------

```
<table  class="table"  ts-wrapper> 
<thead id="testTable">
<th><label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selectAll" ng-change="vm.selectAllResults();">
</label></th>

 function tableScroll () {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element){ 
        element.bind('scroll', function(){
        console.log("scrollingTable");
        //var test =  element[0].scrollHeight - element.scrollTop();
        var test = element.scrollTop();
        scope.test = test;
        console.log(test);
        if(test >= '391'){
            console.log("reached!");
            angular.element($('#testTable')).addClass('tableHeader');
        }
        else if(test<'391'){
            console.log("moreToGo");
            angular.element($('#testTable')).removeClass('tableHeader');
        }    

             });
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With-out seeing more of your real app it's difficult to say what the problem.
But I think you're probably working with `document.ready` from jQuery and that's breaking something.

For code that's working with the DOM you should add your code to the link method of a directive. Then you can work safely with the DOM because it's ready when the link method is invoked.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/v8jn01v0/).

The base code is from this [blog post](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html) I've only added it into a directive.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .directive('sticky', StickyDirective);

function StickyDirective() {
    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
      sticky_relocate();
        }
    };
    
    function sticky_relocate() {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        } else {
            $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
body {
    margin: 1em;
}
p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" sticky="">
<p>Made for my post: <a href="http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html">Stick div at top after scrolling</a>.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque,
    lectus in pharetra blandit, augue mauris pulvinar erat, ut euismod nibh
    lectus sed diam. Nulla fringilla ultrices ligula. Aliquam vitae felis metus.
    Maecenas lacinia bibendum accumsan. Curabitur lobortis convallis purus
    non imperdiet. Morbi ut vulputate mauris. Curabitur lacinia faucibus volutpat.
    Nulla elit tortor, rhoncus ut luctus eget, blandit in risus. Integer accumsan
    ullamcorper lorem id porttitor. Aliquam vitae libero eget magna mollis
    gravida.</p>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ,Thank you for the code snippet,i was trying to implement this in plnkr but it's throwing me an error. This is the problem ,somethings works in plnkr,but doesn't work in the real application.makes me frustrated. Is there anything in angular which fetches the window.scroll like in javascript or in jquery?

Comment: For finding the issues of your real app use the browser console and `console.log` test messages then you can find the issues.  If you don't want to use jQuery for scroll event the js `onscroll` should work too. See the docs [here]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll).

Comment: I know the onscroll() from JS but it is also not working ,i am not a believer of using JQuery in angular .but till now i am not able to solve this issue,Thanks anyways ,i appreciate your response and suggestions

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to use jQuery with angular. I think it's OK to use it if you're using it only inside directives. Anyway I've created a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/thp2jakr/) with-out jQuery. Just with jQueryLite and AngularJs. I don't know how good it is working cross-browser (only tested with Firefox 41.0.2).